# Update selected fields in MongoDB with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

I want my python (scrapy) script to :

- Insert document in my db if url doesn't not exist
- Update only url field if document exists and don't update the other fields.

My script works partially because it inserts a new document if url doesn't exist (that i want) but it updates all the other fields if the document exists (i don't want). Can you help ?

here is a sample :

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

        for data in item:
            if not data:
                raise DropItem("Missing data!")

        self.collection.update({'userurl': item['userurl']}, dict(item), upsert=True)

        return item
```

Thx !

Answer (score 1):

I assume that url and userurl are two different fields otherwise it would be impossible to decide for MongoDB whether the url changed or we have a new record.

Update with `upsert=True` will always change all keys provided. For your particular case you might not get around two queries since you like to update another set of fields than you insert.

Depending on what the more common case is you could reduce the number of actual queries by trying the more common (insert or update) first and issue the other when the first one fails. You can create a unique index on your collection to support such a structure.

Something like this (using the latest `pymongo` API):

```
some_collection.create_index('userurl', unique=True)

try:
    collection.insert_one(dict(item))
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
    res = collection.update_one(
       {'userurl': item['userurl'}, {'$set': {'url': item['url'}})
```

Two things.

You should put the index creation in a place where it happens only once. You don't want to recreate the index over and over again.

You should try the operation that is more common first. However, `update_one` will not fail on filters that return zero records. Check for `res.modified_count == 0` instead.